# Reload parent page after closing popup window

Tags: javascript, popup, window

I am trying to have the user sign in through a popup window.  When they click the link to the popup window which is a php variable they can sign in.  When the window closes I want it to reload the page they were originally on (the parent page).

Here is the code on the signin.php page...

```
<body onunload="opener.location=('')">
```

But all this does is make the sign in page become the page the user was on.  I think I need to put something in the parentheses, but I can't figure out what goes there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Refreshing Parent window after closing popup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398356/refreshing-parent-window-after-closing-popup)

Comment: Why did someone -1 my comment???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To reload a page, you can set the location property as the current value, like this:

```
window.location = window.location;
```

So for your case, you would use, literally:

```
onunload="window.opener.location = window.opener.location;"
```

You can also use the `reload` method of the `location` object:

```
onunload="window.opener.location.reload();"
```

This is the preferred method.

Also, please refer to the accepted answer for your previous question: [Refreshing Parent window after closing popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398356/refreshing-parent-window-after-closing-popup)

**Documentation**

- `window.location` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location
- `window.opener` on MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/Talk:en/DOM/window.opener

Comment: Please +1 my question and ill approve your answer as soon as I can :)

Answer (score -1):

```
echo '<script>window.opener.location.reload()</script>';
echo '<script>self.close()</script>';
```

It works well in all browsers.