# How to reload parent page on closing PopUp window?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have a linkbutton "terms and conditions "on a master page.. when use clicks on it a popup window is displayed  usingthis code

```
Dim myScript As String

            myScript = "<script>window.open('Terms.aspx?',null,'height=750, width=1024,status= no,resizable= no, scrollbars=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,menubar=no'); </script>"

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.[GetType](), "pop", myScript, False)
```

I have a accept button on pop up window page on which i am closing this pop up

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(Page), "closePage", "window.close();", True)
```

The problem is i want to refresh the parent window once this pop up is closed. How can i achieve this? 
This did not work [Refreshing Parent window after closing popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398356/refreshing-parent-window-after-closing-popup)

**UPDATE**

```
<div style="padding:5px 0;">
      <asp:Button ID="btnAccept" runat="server" Text="Accept"  OnClientClick="Refresh()" style="HEIGHT: 19px;background: #C0003B;color: white; " /> &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnReject" runat="server" Text="Reject" OnClientClick="Refresh()" style="HEIGHT: 19px;background: #C0003B;color: white;"/>

</div>
```

```
   function Refresh() {
       return confirm('Are you sure?');
       window.onunload = refreshParent;
       function refreshParent() {
           window.opener.location.reload();
       } 
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access parent window using 'window.opener', so, write something like the following in the child window:

```
onunload="window.opener.location.reload();"
```

or use this

```
<script>
    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
    var retVal = confirm("Are you sure ?");
           if( retVal == true ){
            window.opener.location.reload();
          else
            return false;

    }
</script>
```

Comment: My friend your solution worked like a charm thank you so much.. btw is it possible to add a confirmation dialog box ? something like `return confirm('Are you sure?');`  I tried including it and i was getting the dialog box but then the parent page was not getting refreshed.

Comment: please add code to your question so i can see what you are doing in wrong way or missing.

Comment: its not working.. neither am i seeing any dialog box nor the parent page is getting refreshed.

Comment: nope still not working..the one you updated in answer is neither showing me dialog box nor refreshing the page.. but the javascript that i have posted in the question is showing me the dialog box but no matter what i click "yes" or "no" or "x"(to close)... the result is same. ie. the parent is not getting refreshed and the code behind is getting executed.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37161/discussion-between-sain-pradeep-and-arbaaz)

Comment: @Sian i have got the solution to my other problem .. http://stackoverflow.com/q/18739939/2064292

+1 for your effort.. 
btw is there any difference between `onunload="window.opener.location.reload();"` and the other one you have posted.. keeping the confirmation thing aside.