# javascript confrmation box, executing code behind only if clicked yes

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net

This is following my previous question.. [How to reload parent page on closing PopUp window?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18736603/2064292)

I tried a combination of things but could not make it work.. Sometimes the code behind executes no matter what i chose ie. "yes" , "no" or x(to close) , sometimes.. like the case with the following code.. the code behind never gets executed no matter what option i click..

```
      <asp:Button ID="btnAccept" runat="server" Text="Accept"  OnClientClick="return Refresh()" style="HEIGHT: 19px;background: #C0003B;color: white; " /> &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btnReject" runat="server" Text="Reject" OnClientClick="Refresh()" style="HEIGHT: 19px;background: #C0003B;color: white;"/>


</div>
   <script type="text/javascript">

       function Refresh() {
           var myBoolean = new Boolean();
           myBoolean = confirm('Are you sure?');

           if (myBoolean) {

               window.onunload = refreshParent;

               function refreshParent() {    
                   window.opener.location.reload();
                   return true;
               }
           }
           else {return false;}
       }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this

```
function Refresh() {
    var confirmed = confirm('Are you sure?');

    if (confirmed) {
        window.onunload = refreshParent;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

function refreshParent() {
    window.opener.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: Both of you @johan and bibhu have posted the working solution but since you were the first one to post i am marking yours as an answer. Thanks both of you . :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   function Refresh() {
       var myBoolean = new Boolean();
       if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {

       window.onunload = refreshParent;
       function refreshParent() {

           window.opener.location.reload();
           return true;
       }
   }
       else {return false;}
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution is working fine but since Johan posted the solution first i have marked his post as an answer .. Thanks  :) +1

Comment: there is one little problem with this code... when i click on x(to close the pop up) the code behind gets executed

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a server-side button. Those elements are meant to execute an action in the server.

So guess what? for executing the action on the server this needs to happen:

- The browser submits the form making a POST request
- The server parses the form data and identifies which button was pressed
- The server calls the registered event handler for the button.

So, in your case I would cancel the onclick event of the button in client side. Or simpler... just use a normal HTML button.

```
<button id="btnAccept" onclick="Refresh()" style="HEIGHT: 19px;background: #C0003B;color: white; "> Accept </button>
```

Comment: The else return false chains with the onClientClick="return Refresh()" so it its a workaround for cancelling the click event on the button. That's why I said, you can "cancel" the click event on client side,

Comment: Anyways, using a server side button, for code that needs to be executed on client side is really horrible.

Comment: Thanks, i will keep that in mind from now on.. the reason i did not use a clientside control is that i would have to use `WebMethod`.

Comment: WebMethod? why? an alert() does not need a web method at all.

Comment: its not about alert its about executing code behind, i want to execute code behind when user clicks in accept or reject button and confirms the selection with Yes . Wont i need WebMethod to execude code behind if i use simple html button?