# PHP refresh parent window after closing a child window

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have 3 php files: `view.php`, `edit.php` and `edit2.php`.

`view.php` is where I view the content of my database. I use `edit.php` to enter new data and it's a small window that in which I type in a content I want to include in my db. 
Then, I pass all of the data to `edit2.php` which doesn't display anything but only has implemented MySQL queries.

Now I would like to have something like this:

I'm on `view.php`. I click a button, `edit.php` opens as a new, small window. I enter the data, click SUBMIT button, everything is sent to `edit2.php` but at the same time the window is closed and `view.php` is refreshed.

I would be thankful if you could help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: how r you saving the data?? with ajax??

Comment: I use html post method and I send it to mysql query

Comment: if you are doing this all on server side the user header function of php.else use window.opener.location.reload() after saving data via ajax

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the js function `window.opener.location.reload()`.There is no need of ajax for refreshing the page..Simple js is enough.

Comment: Where should I implement this function?

Comment: You can use it like echo '<script>window.opener.location.reload()</script>';

Comment: Check the usage here..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398356/refreshing-parent-window-after-closing-popup

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean. Should I put this function at the end of edit2.php?

Comment: Ok, I got this. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Add following code to your edit.php

```
    <script>
    window.onunload = refreshParent;
    function refreshParent() {
        window.opener.location.reload();
    }
   </script>
```

Comment: This will open view.php in the small (I called it "child") window and I want to close the child window and at the same time refresh the parent window.

Comment: you mean after execution of edit2.php, you want to open view.php as new window right??

Comment: No. I'm on view.php. I click a button, edit.php shows as a new, small window. I type in what I want to include in my db, click "save" (or whatever button), everything is sent via html post method to edit2.php, but at the same time this small window is closed and the main, big window is refreshed.

Comment: ok.. I understand.. Better you can send request to edit2.php and get success from edit2.php

Comment: if(success){ close.edit2.php and... refresh view.php }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10792408/open-popup-and-refresh-parent-page-on-close-popup refer...

Answer (score 0):

You may use 
     header('Location: view.php'); 
at the end of your edit2.php

Comment: I already answered this, using header("location: view.php"); will open view.php in the small window and I want to close the small window and refresh the main (parent) window.