# Unable to refresh parent window in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I used showModalDialog to open a Popup window from Javascript.  I have this application is ASP.Net and I do post backs in the pop window.

```
 window.showModalDialog('childpage.aspx', '', 'titlebar:no;status:no; help:no; center:yes; edge:raised;dialogWidth:950px;dialogHeight:950px;');
```

In the popup page, I added onunload event to refresh parent page whenever we close the popup.

```
<body onunload="window.opener.reload();">
```

I'm closing the window on a button click in Asp.net using below code:

```
this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Close", "var ua = window.navigator.userAgent; var msie = ua.indexOf(\"MSIE \"); if (msie > 0) { window.close();  } else { parent.document.getElementsByTagName('dialog')[0].close();  }", true);
```

It works fine in IE. In Chrome, I could close the window, but I am unable to refresh the page. Even closing popup in Chrome is not straight-forward. window.close doesn't work so I used a condition inside my script above to close the popup based on browser.  Can anyone advise on how to refresh the parent page when browser is chrome?  I have tried all the previous suggestions in this forum and other forums but no luck!!

I tried this too...

```
this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Close", "var ua = window.navigator.userAgent; var msie = ua.indexOf(\"MSIE \"); var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined'; if (msie > 0 || isFirefox) { window.close();  } else { parent.document.getElementsByTagName('dialog')[0].close();  } window.opener.location.reload(true);", true);
```

Comment: Have you tried the onbeforeunload event, rather than onunload?

Comment: yes, I tried that too!! but, it doesn't refresh parent window in Chrome!!

Comment: `showModalDialog` has been depreciated in Chrome a long time ago. How do you manage to make it work at all, what version of Chrome are u using?

Comment: It is working; I'm able to open dialog, do my stuff inside with all postbacks; but I faced issues closing and refreshing parent; but I figured a way to close the window but not refreshing parent. My Version 44.0.2403.130 m

Comment: if it is issue with modaldialog, is there an alternative way to open modaldialog for non-chrome and poup for other browsers?

Comment: In the child page, have you tried `window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function() { window.opener.reload(); });` ?

Comment: I have tried this as well. But, no luck!! Chrome behaves strange!!

Answer (score 2):

@user2169261

I had a similar problem with chrome. the parent window in firefox and IE could refresh correctly but not in chrome. below is the code that I used to get it to work:

Parent window code (file name: test.php)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Parent window</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>This is the Parent window.</h2>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" NAME=""  title=""
    onClick=window.open("test2.php","Ratting","width=550,height=170,0,status=0,top=200,");>
    Click here to open the child window</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Child window code (file name: test2.php)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Child Window</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function refreshAndClose()
{
    window.close();
    if (window.opener && !window.opener.closed) 
    {
      window.opener.location.reload();
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>     
<h2>Click the button below to close this window and refresh the parent window</h2>     
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="return refreshAndClose()"/>        
</body>
</html>
```

This might not be exactly what you are looking for but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (Chrome 55.0.2883.87 Windows 10) in the end the only solution that worked was here: [Refresh Parent page on close of pop up window](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11398717/276874).  All credit to original answer but my version here for speed

```
var windowRef = window.open("http://www.google.de");
var monitor = setInterval(function () {
        if (windowRef.closed) {
            document.location.assign(getRefreshUrl(window.location));
            clearInterval(monitor);
        }
    }, 100);
```

Super nasty to have a setInterval I know, but the only way it would work for me in Chrome.